# Creating centroid layer from selection using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, centroids

I'm trying to create a centroid layer from a selection with Python.

I manage to make a selection based on features with expression :

```
code_com = '001'
section = '\'0A\''
numero = '0502'

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression('"CODE_COM"='+code_com+' and "SECTION"='+section+' and "NUMERO"='+numero)
```

But when I try to create a centroid layer on selected features, the layer does create but without any centroid. The attribute table is empty.

```
outFile = r'C:\path\to\new\file\centroid.shp'

feats = layer.selectedFeatures()
fields = layer.fields()

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(outFile, 'UTF-8', fields, QgsWkbTypes.Point, 
layer.sourceCrs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')

for feat in feats:
    geom = feat.geometry()
    centr = geom.centroid()
    feat.setGeometry(centr)
    writer.addFeature(feat)

iface.addVectorLayer(outFile, '', 'ogr')
del(writer)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: you are switching from a polygon to a point with out changing the geometry type

Comment: For me your code works fine. The only thing I changed was the file path. Are you sure you have features that match your expression? Does the `feats` list contain anything?

Comment: @IanTurton the geometry type of the original layer is irrelevant as the centroids of its features are being written to a Point layer.

Comment: @Matt - that's not what the code above is doing, `feats` are the selected features of the original layer, so the `geom` field is expecting a polygon

Comment: The feature's geometry type is being overwritten before being added to the writer. It is not best practice, I certainly agree with that, but it is working.

Comment: Hi @Matt, hi IanTurton thanks for your answers. The feats list contains the feat for the selected element this is why I don't understand. What would be the cleanest way to do it ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, it is probably better to create a new feature rather than forcing a different geometry type on an existing feature.

In the solution below, a new feature is created and configured before sending it to the writer.

The problem of no features appearing in your output layer might be that there is a `'` missing from the end of your expression.

Here I have used an [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) to compose your expression (rather than concatenating the strings with `+`), and made sure that `'`s are properly escaped with `\`.

```py
code_com = '001'
section = '0A'
numero = '0502'

layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.selectByExpression(f'"CODE_COM"=\'{code_com}\' and "SECTION"=\'{section}\' and "NUMERO"=\'{numero}\'')

outFile = r'C:\path\to\new\file\centroid.shp'

feats = layer.selectedFeatures()
fields = layer.fields()

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(outFile, 'UTF-8', fields, QgsWkbTypes.Point, 
layer.sourceCrs(), 'ESRI Shapefile')


for feat in feats:
    # create a new feature rather than overwrite geometry of an existing feature
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    # copy the attributes from the current polygon to the new feature
    new_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    geom = feat.geometry()
    centr = geom.centroid()
    # set the geometry of the new feature as the centroid of the existing one
    new_feat.setGeometry(centr)
    writer.addFeature(new_feat)

iface.addVectorLayer(outFile, '', 'ogr')
del(writer)
```

###### *Note:*

*Without seeing your data, I don't know if the escaped quotation marks `\'` are necessary in your `section` variable. If they are, then be sure to replace them if you copy-paste my entire snippet.*